# Custom sort durations using jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I need to sort a column in jQuery DataTables. I tried using the moment plugin without success.

The column contains call duration but it's not always there so we use `N/A` for those. Column data looks like:

```
2m 45s
1m 32s
N/A
45s
1m
```

I need to be able to sort these with the `N/A` valuing less than `0` and the rest to be in the logical order

I use jQuery DataTables 1.10.6, moment 2.9.0 and I do have all the datatables plugins. I use `data-stype` is `th` in the header of my table. I also use the no config datatable init looks like that

```
// Create DataTables User
    table = $('#summary-table').DataTable({
        'language'  : { "url": paths.lang_{{LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale()}} },
        'responsive':
        {
            'details':
            {
                'type': 'inline'
            }
        },
        'order': [[(nbCat + 5), 'desc']],
        'dom': '<"row"<"col-sm-12 before-table
               "<"table_controls">>r><"row"<"col-sm-12"t>><"row"<"col-sm-12"ipl>>',
        'lengthMenu': [[20, 50, 100, -1], [20, 50, 100, transAll]],
    });
```

Comment: JQueryUI has just the thing you want: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Not quite what im looking for, it need to reoder a whole table by clicking the header. From what i see in the link its mouse sorted

Comment: I have used it in a web-app that I am working on and upon clicking on table-headers sorts entire table columns, all done with about 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

Use the code below:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "duration-pre": function (s) {        
        var duration;
        
        s = s.toLowerCase();
        
        if(s === 'n/a'){ 
            duration = -1;
            
        } else {            
            d = s.match(/(?:(\d+)m)?\s*(?:(\d+)s)?/);
            duration = parseInt(d[1] ? d[1] : 0) * 60 + parseInt(d[2] ? d[2] : 0);
        }
        
        return duration;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#summary-table').DataTable({
       columnDefs: [
           { targets: 0, type: 'duration' }
       ]         
    });
});
```

Change `0` in `targets: 0` to index of the column containing the duration. I omitted other table options for the sake of simplicity.

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qq6moapt/1/) for code and demonstration.